# Umbraco - Installation & database

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I've begin the development of my Umbraco Website. I've forgot to include a database on the setup so I think that all my stuff is in the cache. Am I right ?

However, I've tried to include a connection string, all is fine, Umbraco can connect to my database, but now Umbraco is looping on the Installation page and do nothing.

My database is empty and on any url Umbraco is trying to install.

I'm using Umbraco 7.6.3

How can i add my database so all the stuff I've made is not lost ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Alex,

when you use the default settings during installation of Umbraco, then it wil use SQL CE.

This method will save all data not in SQL server but in a local sdf file which is located in the `App_Data` folder.

If you want to change this, then the best way will be to start over the entire installation incase you haven't add any elements to your existing version.

Then during installation you can choose to specify other options for the database, like adding the database to your Sql Server instance.

If you want to convert your existing SQL CE database to sql server, have a look here:

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/53818-Convert-Umbraco-SQL-CE-database-to-SQL-Express